# Change size of Twitter Bootstrap's Image Carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this code:

```
   <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                        </ol>
                        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                            <div class="carousel-item active">
                                <img class="d-block img-fluid"
                                     src="http://www.public-domain-photos.com/free-cliparts-4/computer/actions/ok.png"
                                     alt="First slide">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://k36.kn3.net/CA1AEE661.jpg"
                                     alt="Second slide">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block img-fluid"
                                     src="http://www.public-domain-photos.com/free-cliparts-4/computer/actions/ok.png"
                                     alt="Third slide">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button"
                           data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button"
                           data-slide="next">
                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have taken these 3 random images as example. Their resolution is much bigger, but it is shown rather small in my project.

When I try to make my own CSS class, instead of col-sm-4, the carousel stops working.

How do I resize the carousel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using class `carousel-item` use class `item` or you can use both. Just make sure to have `item` class at least.

Try this way.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                        </ol>
                        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                            <div class="carousel-item item active">
                                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://www.public-domain-photos.com/free-cliparts-4/computer/actions/ok.png" alt="First slide">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item item">
                                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://k36.kn3.net/CA1AEE661.jpg" alt="Second slide">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item item">
                                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://www.public-domain-photos.com/free-cliparts-4/computer/actions/ok.png" alt="Third slide">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Left and right controls -->
                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```